# All Paragraph in Article Tag Scraping with BeautifulSoup - Main Target the A-tag

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Search some of the similar question but didn't pull it off.

I'm trying to get the A-Tags inside a Paragraph Tag inside the Article Tag. Tried it on: "holly willoughby weight loss" page and it's working fine, did manage to get the article post inside a paragraph tag and manage to get the target A-tag. But trying on a different URL (The example URL below) on the same website I am only getting post header and some CSS.

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://burniva.com/sam-smith-weight-loss/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
posts = soup.article
print(posts)
```

When using "requests", It pulls all the a-tags fine but whenever I try:

```
soup.article
```

It fails to get all 'p' inside the article.

Comment: We get quite a lot of spam for weight loos scams, are the links in your question really useful and necessary? Probably you should excerpt the HTML you are having trouble with into the question itself instead

Comment: @tripleee yes it's necessary. It's on the same website, that's the one I had a success but not every page on the website accept my mini scraper. Other pages like on the 'url' has it's 'p' divided. I left that one so If someone would be kind enough to check my problem out, he/she can also test both one having the success and one that isn't and could give me a valid reason is to why that's happening. No scam intended.

Comment: The problem with that is that the question will no longer be answerable if you change anything on the site. The question should be self-contained and reproducible even if you figure out how to fix the problem; this is necessary for it to be useful to future visitors, which is an important consideration on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @tripleee there, removed it. Really serious and curious on how to the pull the problem?